# Axiom of Limitation of Size implies Axiom of Union?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

On The Wikipedia page for Axiom of limitation of size it states that this axiom can be used to prove the axiom of union: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size

> It implies the axiom schema of specification, axiom schema of replacement, axiom of global choice, and even, as noticed later by Azriel Levy, axiom of union[2] at one stroke.

I understand the first three axioms mentioned, but I haven't been able to find anything regarding the axiom of union. Does anyone know how this axiom implies the other? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Never mind, I did a little more searching and I **finally** found the information I was looking for. Sorry for the hassle. Here's where I found it: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315201?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be any set, and for each $s\in S$, take a nonempty set $s'$ such that there is no surjection $s\to s'$ (e.g., $s'=P(s)$).  Then by [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)), there is no surjection $\bigcup S\to \prod_{s\in S} s'$.  By limitation of size, this implies $\bigcup S$ cannot be a proper class, since any proper class surjects onto $V$ (and hence onto any nonempty class).  That is, $\bigcup S$ is a set.