# Axiom of Limitation of Size implies Axiom of Union?

Tags: set-theory

I am re-asking the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918464/axiom-of-limitation-of-size-implies-axiom-of-union) which was not answered.

On The Wikipedia page for Axiom of Limitation of Size it states that this axiom can be used to prove the axiom of union: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size

> It implies the axiom schema of specification, axiom schema of
> replacement, axiom of global choice, and even, as noticed later by
> Azriel Levy, axiom of union at one stroke.

The reference given in Wikipedia is to Levy, Azriel (1968), "On Von Neumann's Axiom System for Set Theory", American Mathematical Monthly, 75 (7): 762–763, doi:10.2307/2315201, JSTOR 2315201.

Unfortunately this paper is not readily available to amateur or hobby mathematicians, and extensive googling has not yielded anything useful. Can someone please outline a proof or provide a reference.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can make a JSTOR account and read 100 articles a month for free.

Comment: Anyways, I've written an answer with (a simplified version of) Levy's argument at the old question.

Comment: Thanks, excellent :)